# Print output for class attendance system in array

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

I'm designing an attendance system, my problem is i don't know how to show the input form the attendance. Here is a brief of my system.

Every student have their matrix number and password. The user will input their matrix number and password. If the matrix number and password is correct, the system will show a message dialog.

I don't know how to save the input and then show it into the array.

source code :

```
public class TESTARRAY {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input1;



         // Creating array

       String[][] multi =  { {"40604", "MUHAMAD SYAMIL HAIQAL BIN KAMARUZZAMAN",""},
       {"40599","NIK MUHAMMAD 'INWAN BIN NIK ADNAN",""},
       {"37027","HARNANI BINTI ABDUL MAJID",""},
       {"37067","NURUL ASHIKIN BINTI MOHD FAZLI",""},
       {"37064","NURLIYANA BINTI MOHD KAMAL",""},
       {"37045","NADIATUL NAJIHAH BINTI MOHD NAZRI ",""},
       { "37065","NURSUHAILA BINTI MAD SALIM ",""}
       };


      printArray(multi);
   }


   public static void printArray(String[][] num1) {

       String input2;
       String input3;
       int password;
       int matricnumber;
       int a = 0;
       String  input4;



       boolean one = true;


       String[] columnNames = { "MATRIX NUMBER", "NAME","ATTENENDE"};


     String[][] input1 = new String[num1.length][num1[0].length];
      for (int i = 0; i < input1.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < input1[i].length; j++) {

             input1[i][j] = num1[i][j];
            }
           }



      DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(input1, columnNames);
      JTable table = new JTable(model);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollPane, "CLASS ATTENDANCE",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);






      //for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

           while (one== true)
      {

         input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter Your Matric Number " );
           matricnumber = Integer.parseInt(input2);


          input3=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter  Your Password: " );
          password = Integer.parseInt(input3);

          input4=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Attendende : " );
          password = Integer.parseInt(input4);




          if (matricnumber==40604&&password==11){

              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hi "+num1[0][1]+""+num1[0][3]+" ("+input2+").\nYou have attend the class. Enjoy the class\nThank you " );

              //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The student that attend the class for today:\n"+num1[0][1]+" ("+input2+" )");


               input4=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Press 0 to stop or other number to continue " );
             a = Integer.parseInt(input4);

              switch(input4){

                  case"0":one=false;
                      break;


              }


          }

          else if (matricnumber==40599&&password==22){

                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hi "+num1[1][1]+""+num1[1][3]+" ("+input2+").\nYou have attend the class. Enjoy the class\nThank you" );

                      //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The student that attend the class for today:\n"+num1[1][1]+" ("+input2+" )");

                       input4=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Press 0 to stop or other number to continue " );
              a = Integer.parseInt(input4);

              switch(input4){

                 case"0":one=false;
                   break;
              }
          }

          else if (matricnumber==37027&&password==33){

                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hi "+num1[2][1]+""+num1[2][3]+" ("+input2+").\nYou have attend the class. Enjoy the class\nThank you" );
                      //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The student that attend the class for today:\n"+num1[2][1]+" ("+input2+" )");

                       input4=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Press 0 to stop or other number to continue " );
              a = Integer.parseInt(input4);

              switch(input4){

               case"0":one=false;
                break;
              }

          }

          else if (matricnumber==37067&&password==44){

                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hi "+num1[3][1]+""+num1[3][3]+" ("+input2+").\nYou have attend the class. Enjoy the class\nThank you" );

                       //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The student that attend the class for today:\n"+num1[3][1]+" ("+input2+" )");

                       input4=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Press 0 to stop or other number to continue " );
              a = Integer.parseInt(input4);

              switch(input4){

                  case"0":one=false;
                      break;
              }

          }

          else if (matricnumber==37064&&password==55){

                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hi "+num1[4][1]+""+num1[4][3]+" ("+input2+").\nYou have attend the class. Enjoy the class\nThank you" );
                      //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The student that attend the class for today:\n"+num1[4][1]+" ("+input2+" )");

                       input4=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Press 0 to stop or other number to continue " );
              a = Integer.parseInt(input4);

              switch(input4){

                  case"0":one=false;
                      break;
              }
          }

          else if (matricnumber==37045&&password==66){

                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hi "+num1[5][1]+""+num1[5][3]+" ("+input2+")\nYou have attend the class. Enjoy the class\nThank you" );
                      //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The student that attend the class for today:\n"+num1[5][1]+" ("+input2+" )");

                       input4=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Press 0 to stop or other number to continue " );
              a = Integer.parseInt(input4);

              switch(input4){

                  case"0":one=false;
                      break;
              }
          }

         else if (matricnumber==37065&&password==77){

                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hi "+num1[6][1]+""+num1[6][3]+" ("+input2+").\nYou have attend the class. Enjoy the class\nThank you" );
                      //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The student that attend the class for today:\n"+num1[6][1]+" ("+input2+" )");

                       input4=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Press 0 to stop or other number to continue " );
              a = Integer.parseInt(input4);

              switch(input4){

                  case"0":one=false;
                      break;
              }

      }

      else 

                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You are not the student in this class. GET OUT !!!" );
           input4=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Press 0 to stop or other number to continue " );
              a = Integer.parseInt(input4);

              switch(input4){

                  case"n":one=false;
                     break;
              }




           } 


        String input5;
         String[][] ulti =  { {"40604", "MUHAMAD SYAMIL HAIQAL BIN KAMARUZZAMAN","num1[0][2]"},
       {"40599","NIK MUHAMMAD 'INWAN BIN NIK ADNAN","num2[1][3]"},
       {"37027","HARNANI BINTI ABDUL MAJID","num2[2][3]"},
       {"37067","NURUL ASHIKIN BINTI MOHD FAZLI","num2[3][3]"},
       {"37064","NURLIYANA BINTI MOHD KAMAL","num2[4][3]"},
       {"37045","NADIATUL NAJIHAH BINTI MOHD NAZRI ","num2[5][3]"},
       { "37065","NURSUHAILA BINTI MAD SALIM ","num2[6][3]"}
       };


      printA(ulti);
           }

       public static void printA(String[][] num2){ 



       String[] columnNames = { "MATRIX NUMBER", "NAME","ATTENDENCE"};


     String[][] input5 = new String[num2.length][num2[0].length];
      for (int i = 0; i < input5.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < input5[i].length; j++) {

             input5[i][j] = num2[i][j];
            }
           }



      DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(input5, columnNames);
      JTable table = new JTable(model);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollPane, "CLASS ATTENDANCE",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }   
   }
```

Comment: First, you should use different methods and not blast up one. After, you should add some try-catch blocks (for example: NumberFormatExceptions). 
Then maybe is better to give your data-model few minutes more time. So why not a own "User" class how handle the specifics methods? So you can easier check your input with the datas.

Answer (score 1):

You should really extract you data to own class like:

```
public class User {
    String name;
    int maxtrix;
    int attend;

    public User(int matrix, String name, int attend) {
        this.name = name;
        this.maxtrix = matrix;
        this.attend = attend;
    }

    public boolean checkCredentials(int matrix, int attend) {
        if (matrix == this.maxtrix && attend == this.attend) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This data-class works perfectly with a list.. Look this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        // Creating users       
        users.add(new User(40604, "MUHAMAD SYAMIL HAIQAL BIN KAMARUZZAMAN", 0));
        users.add(new User(40599, "NIK MUHAMMAD 'INWAN BIN NIK ADNAN", 0));
        users.add(new User(37027, "HARNANI BINTI ABDUL MAJID", 0));
        users.add(new User(37067, "NURUL ASHIKIN BINTI MOHD FAZLI", 0));
        users.add(new User(37064, "NURLIYANA BINTI MOHD KAMAL", 0));
        users.add(new User(37045, "NADIATUL NAJIHAH BINTI MOHD NAZRI ", 0));
        users.add(new User(37065, "NURSUHAILA BINTI MAD SALIM ", 0));

        printArray(users);
    }
```

And now it's easier to fill you table and check the user's input (you could iterate over the user-list and use **checkCredentials** to check)

Answer (score 0):

First of all create an array that includes all user input.

```
 String[] user_input={input2, input3, input4}
```

Then you search if this array does exist in your two-dimensional array.

```
public boolean searchMultiArray(user_input){

 boolean b=false;

 for(int i=0; i<multi.length; i++){

     if(java.utils.Arrays.equals(multi[i], user_input){

          b=true;
          break;
     } 
  }

 return b;
}
```